# How to replace content in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function show(question,answer)
{        
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question;       
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;               
}
```

I need to replace single quotes `'` with `\'` in question and answer.

Comment: `question.replace( /'/g, "\\'" )` and `answer.replace( /'/g, "\\'" )`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var question = "this is ' new ' question ' from my side";
  var answer = "this is ' new ' answer ' from my side";
  showContent(question, answer);
});

function showContent(question, answer) {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = ReplaceString(question,"'","\\'");
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = ReplaceString(answer, "'", "\\'");
}

function ReplaceString(message, oldString, newString) {        
  return message.split(oldString).join(newString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="answer"></div>
```